# Using MAX and returning whole row with max column value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL and struggling with finding a working solution for my MAX situation.

I currently have a table that looks like:

```
ID   Date         Version
001  2010-11-17   2
001  2010-12-01   3
002  2011-01-11   1
002  2011-05-05   2
```

My desired result is simply:

```
ID   Date        Version
001  2010-12-01  3
002  2011-05-05  2
```

I can't use MAX and GROUP BY on date since Date is not distinct.

Comment: Appologies, realised my question is not very clear.  I basically want the rows with the highest version number for each ID. thanks

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm using SQL server 2008. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT     ID,
           Date,
           Version
FROM       YourTable
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT    ID,
              Max(Version)
    FROM      YourTable
    GROUP BY  ID
) AS x
ON         YourTable.ID = x.ID
AND        YourTable.Version = x.Version
```

Comment: For very large datasets with large numbers of versions per row, this often is the optimal solution (if properly indexed).

Comment: +1 this is fine unless there are duplicate version numbers. But from what OP's written I suppose there'ren't.

Comment: I mean thanks to Maximilian! Sorry lost track of the original poster. thanks all :)

Comment: In some scenario we have one data (date-time column for exam) for ID and Id is not repeated, so grouping by ID will return all record and we need to return MAX(ID), MAX(date-time column) without grouping by in sub-query to got record ID has Max date-time value.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `row_number` for that, like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() OVER(partition by id order by version desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution but you should point out that it will only work with newer version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

For versions of SQL-Server that have window functions:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Version
FROM
  ( SELECT ID, Date, Version
         , MAX(Version) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS MaxVersion
    FROM yourtable
  ) AS tmp
WHERE Version = MaxVersion
```

Comment: In SQL Server, "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: @Andomar: thnx, I should check before posting.

Comment: @Andomar: fixed. Not sure but probably your version is faster.